# What causes trade routes to be broken?

Tags: civilization-5

My general question is:
**What can cause trade routes to be broken?**

My specific question is:
**Why was the route between my cities broken?**
As you can see they are connected by road. There are no barbarians. I have no enemies nearby and no other civilizations on my island.

[image]
[image]
[Click for larger version of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nbfd.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your image I can tell two things:

1. That your two cities both have a harbor.
2. That your two cities are still actually connected.

You can tell that they are connected by looking at Shanghai. Right underneath the city name for Shanghai, there's a small black circle with three yellow dots [image: city connection icon]. This icon means that you have a trade route with your capital city.

The reason you received a message that the trade route was broken, was most likely because you built a harbor in both cities. When you do so, the game changes your trade route from by land/road to by sea. It is a bit misleading because this "a trade route has been broken" prompt still comes up, and is technically correct, but in reality your trade route is just changing from via road to via sea.

Answer (score -5):

i can clearly see that there's a part of the road outside your territory and Shangai's territory. I think it's due to that. They change this behaviour almost at every new version, so if you grew up with other Civ Games, you would ignore that.

Comment: A road does not have to be in my territory to have cities connected. Note the problem was that on this turn, the trade route was broken. Now in CIV5, you cannot remove territory from your cultural border unless you raze a city.

Comment: Then probably i confused Civ5 with Civ4.